# Occurring errors with next.js production application

Tags: next.js, hadoop-yarn, production

I have facing issues with next.js application when I runned next.js app into production mode the cmd not working, after installed the yarn build command I want to start the production application by command "yarn start". I found still an error "Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\bahad\OneDrive\Documents\next-application.next\prerender-manifest.json". I tried with npm, reinstalled the node_modules, created a new app but still error occuring. Have you any idea about error, thanks?

Resolve facing issue.